# Simple byte changing with fgetc/fwrite fails

Tags: c++, file, fopen, fwrite

## UPDATE

I solved it with the answer that's marked as *valid*, but with one slight difference. I open the file using `fopen(file, "r+b")`, not `fopen(file, "r+")`. The `b` opens it in binary mode, and doesn't screw up the file.

---

I was doing a simple program which I called "fuzzer".
This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    // Here go some checks, such as argc being correct, etc.
    // ...

    // Read source file
    FILE *fSource;
    fSource = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    if(fSource == NULL){
        cout << "Can't open file!";
        return 2;
    }

    // Loop source file
    char b;
    int i = 0;
    while((b = fgetc(fSource)) != EOF){
        b ^= 0x13;
        fseek(fSource, i++, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&b, 1, sizeof(b), fSource);
    }

    fclose(fSource);
    cout << "Fuzzed.";

    return 0;
}
```

However, it doesn't work. Before, I used `while(!feof)`, but it didn't work either, and [I saw that it's not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong), so I changed it to `(b = fgetc()) != EOF` (I suppose it's correct, right?).

When I run it, it gets stuck on an endless loop, and it doesn't modify the original file, but rather appends tildes to it (and the file quickly increases its size, until I stop it). If I change the open mode from "a+" to "r+", it simply deletes the contents of the file (but it at least doesn't get stuck in an endless loop).

**Note**: I understand that this isn't any kind of obfuscation or *encryption*. I'm not trying to *encode* files, just practicing with C++ and files.

Comment: I am unsure about this line `fwrite(&b, 1, sizeof(b), fSource);` In you code b is just a single char, not an array. When you call '&b' you are passing the address of b, where i am pretty sure you should just pass 'b'.

Comment: @Elias: wrong, look up the documentation for `fwrite`. It can write any number of characters from an address, including 1.

Comment: AcidShout: what happens if you `fseek(fSource, i, SEEK_SET);` at the end of the while loop?

Comment: @immibis absolutely nothing. Stays exactly like it was before

Comment: It shouldn't really affect the correctness of your program, but if you're using `fgetc()` to read, why not use `fputc()` to write?  Strictly, you need a positioning operation (such as `fseek()`) after the write (`fwrite()`) as well as after the read.  It is also best to report errors to `cerr` rather than `cout`, and to include the name of the file in the message when you fail to open the file.

Comment: `char b;` needs to be `int b;`. If you're not sure why, then read the documentation of `fgetc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me when tested on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative with GCC 4.9.0:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " file\n";
      return 1;
    }

    FILE *fSource = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    if (fSource == NULL)
    {
        cerr << "Can't open file: " << argv[1] << "\n";
        return 2;
    }

    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(fSource)) != EOF)
    {
        char b = c ^ 0x13;
        fseek(fSource, i++, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&b, 1, sizeof(b), fSource);
        fseek(fSource, i, SEEK_SET);
    }

    fclose(fSource);
    cout << "Fuzzed: " << argv[1] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It reports file names; it reports errors to standard error (`cerr`); it uses `int c;` to read the character, but copies that to `char b` so that the `fwrite()` works.  When run on (a copy of) its own source code, the first time the output looks like gibberish, and the second time recovers the original.

This loop, using `fputc()` instead of `fwrite()`, also works without needing the intermediate variable `b`:

```
    while ((c = fgetc(fSource)) != EOF)
    {
        fseek(fSource, i++, SEEK_SET);
        fputc(c ^ 0x13, fSource);
        fseek(fSource, i, SEEK_SET);
    }
```

The use of an `fseek()` after the read *and* after the write is mandated by the C standard.  I'm not sure whether that's the main cause of your trouble, but it could in theory be one of the issues.

Comment: Works! First, I've corrected my code to use `cerr` and proper output. Then, I tried using `fputc`, but nothing. Finally, I found out that I **must** use `fseek` before and after writing. My code now looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/01ZgMf17) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need `int b;`. A `char` can never be `EOF`. [The manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) describes all this. All in all, something like this:

```
for (int b, i = 0; (b = fgetc(fSource)) != EOF; ++i)
{
    unsigned char x = b;
    x ^= 0x13;
    fseek(fSource, i, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&x, 1, 1, fSource);
    fseek(fSource, i + 1, SEEK_SET);
}
```

You should also open the file with mode `"rb+"`, and seek between each read and write (thanks @Jonathan Leffler).

Comment: I tried (and indeed, you are right, it's `int`, not `char`), but it still says "Fuzzed." with no results (aka the file remains untouched)

Comment: You need a positioning operation after the write as well as after the read, because the C standard says so, and the code is mainly C code except for the error messages which are incorrectly reported to standard output (`cout`) rather than `cerr` or `clog`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Interesting, I was looking around but couldn't see anything specific. It seems to me that both `fread` and `fwrite` just advance the offset by the amount of data they transferred. That's what the hook description in `fopencookie` says, too. So the final `fwrite` in the loop should leave the cursor at the next unread position...?

Comment: @KerrekSB: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.5.3 **The `fopen` function**, ¶7 _When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the
above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the
associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an
intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`,
`fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-
file._